# Subscripts and capital letters surpressed in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization, subscripts

My article title contains subscripts and capital letters for the molecular formulas. This reference I downloaded from Google Scholar. However, the subscripts and the capital letters are not displayed correctly in the bibliography.

Does any one know a solution to this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: bibliography display]

```
    @article{tonndorf2013photoluminescence,
  title={Photoluminescence emission and Raman response of monolayer MoS< sub> 2</sub>, MoSe< sub> 2</sub>, and WSe< sub> 2</sub>},
author={Tonndorf, Philipp and Schmidt, Robert and B{\"o}ttger, Philipp and Zhang, Xiao and B{\"o}rner, Janna and Liebig, Andreas and Albrecht, Manfred and Kloc, Christian and Gordan, Ovidiu and Zahn, Dietrich RT and others},
journal={Optics express},
volume={21},
number={4},
pages={4908--4916},
year={2013},
publisher={Optical Society of America}
}
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{cite}



\begin{document}

 Trying to get the title displayed correctly in the bibliography for this article \cite{tonndorf2013}

 \bibliography{bibfile}{}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrt}


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the letters (or words) you want to keep in capitalized format inside a group `{..}`. Also, remove the HTML formatting and substitute that for a regular `\textsubscript` (provided by [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{tonndorf2013photoluminescence,
  title={Photoluminescence emission and {R}aman response of monolayer {MoS}\textsubscript{2}, {MoSe}\textsubscript{2}, and {WSe}\textsubscript{2}},
  author={Tonndorf, Philipp and Schmidt, Robert and B{\"o}ttger, Philipp and Zhang, Xiao and B{\"o}rner, Janna and Liebig, Andreas and Albrecht, Manfred and Kloc, Christian and Gordan, Ovidiu and Zahn, Dietrich RT and others},
  journal={Optics express},
  volume={21},
  number={4},
  pages={4908--4916},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Optical Society of America}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{refstyle,cite,fixltx2e}

\begin{document}

Trying to get the title displayed correctly in the bibliography for this article \cite{tonndorf2013photoluminescence}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```