# bibliography not showing capital letters for words in "title" field for entries of type "@article"

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization

I have a bib file with most words in the `title` all capitalized. For instance:

```
@article{ekstrom2013family,
    Author = {Ekstr{\"o}m, Mats and {\"O}stman, Johan},
    Date-Added = {2019-03-06 17:27:29 -0800},
    Date-Modified = {2019-03-06 17:48:19 -0800},
    Journal = {European Journal of Communication},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {294-308},
    Publisher = {Sage Publications Sage UK: London, England},
    Title = {Family Talk, Peer Talk and Young People's Civic Orientation},
    Volume = {28},
    Year = {2013}}
```

However, the pdf output does not show these capitals -- the article titles are all turned to lowercase. What would be causing this issue?

In the preamble, I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[margin = .75in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position = top, font = large}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lscape}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=Violet,
  linkcolor=Red,
  urlcolor=Blue}
```

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173990/1952

Comment: Capitalization rules for the contents of `title` fields are determined by the bibliography style that's in use. Which style do you employ? By the way, `natbib` does *not* influence the uppercasing or lowercasing of words in the `title` field.

Comment: @Mico I tried both apalike and plainnat

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't load both `natbib` and `cite`. Use one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: This is very confusing! Neither `plainnat` nor `apalike` apply "sentence style" (with lowercasing of all words not encased in curly braces) to the contents of the `title` field for entries of type `@book`. Are you maybe concerned about lowercasing of titles of entries of type `@article` or `@techreport`?

Comment: @Mico Yes, you were right -- the problem is with the journal article titles. I will fix my question.

Comment: I absolutely agree with daleif that it is preferable to wrap entire word in braces, not just individual letters to avoid negative effects on kerning. I should also add that I'm against simply protecting all words in a title to get around the sentence casing feature of a style. Either accept the output the style produces (sentence case instead of Title Case), switch to a different style or modify the style to stop applying sentence case.

Comment: Off-topic: Note that formally the packages `cite` and `natbib` are incompatible. In many situations they can coexist peacefully, but there are examples where documents loading both packages break. For most intents and purposes `natbib` is more powerful than `cite`. Note also that usually `hyperref` should be the last package you load (only very few packages need to be loaded after `hyperref`: `cleveref` is one of them, `cite` and `etoolbox` are not, they should be loaded before `hyperref`).