# Capital letters are not capital in the entries titles in `natbib`

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use `IEEEtranN` for a bibliography style in my thesis. This is the output I get for one reference.

[image]

This happens even after using the solution in [Subscripts and capital letters surpressed in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173984/subscripts-and-capital-letters-surpressed-in-bibliography)

I tried to save the original document with another name, leave the preamble unmodified, and remove all contents in the document and try to cite the same reference again, I get

[image]

This applies to some references only. The solution in [Subscripts and capital letters surpressed in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173984/subscripts-and-capital-letters-surpressed-in-bibliography)
 (using `{}` around the letters I want to capitalize) seem to work for some most references but not all.

The MWE works well, but in the actual document itself I do not get the desired output. Of course, I cannot gradually remove parts of the document and recompile multiple times because each time I compile it, I need to wait for 2 to 3 minutes.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@techreport{NRELWestern2015,
    title = {{Western Wind and Solar Integration {S}tudy {P}hase 3{A}: Low Levels of Synchronous Generation}},
    author = {Miller, Nicholas and Leonardi, Bruno and D'Aquila, Robert},
    group = {NERC},
    institution = {NERC},
    year = {2015},
    month = {Nov},
    Date-Added = {2015},
    Date-Modified = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[round]{natbib} % natbib is very common and reliable bibliography management package

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true} % link color of citations goes here
                \hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\begin{document}

\cite{NRELWestern2015}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} % style of bibliography (here you specify that you want authoryear or numeric citation)
\bibliography{sample} % defines the file that contains information about the article you cite

\end{document}
```

Comment: If we cannot reproduce the problem it will be very difficult to figure out the solution. Maybe you could give reducing the document a try after all? When you remove a large chunk, for example a few chapters at the same time (while making sure the remaining chapters still contain the problematic references) then the compile time should go down fast. Or try to remove particularly time-consuming elements, like big TikZ drawings or large images (or compile with `draft` or `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` etc).

Comment: You could also check if there is a specific type of reference that doesn't work in your full document (if the problem is with `techreport` but not with `inproceedings`, for example), or something else that is special about the problematic entries, such as apostrophes or something. Or look in the `.bbl` file and/or the `.blg` file to see if there is some clue (there may not be anything there, but without a reproducable problem it's only possible to guess).